# Java 16 Annotation ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT cannot be reflected

Tags: java, reflection, java-record, java-16

Using JDK 16, I declared two annotations:

```
@Target({ ElementType.RECORD_COMPONENT})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {}

@Target({ ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface B {}
```

And I declared a record class like this：

```
public record User(@A @B long id, String name, int age) {}
```

Then I use reflection to fetch the annotations of id, which is:

```
Annotation[] annotations = fields[0].getAnnotations();
```

But the size of `annotations` is one and I only got `@B`, why is that? Thanks

Comment: Since `ElementType.FIELD` has not been specified as `@Target` for `A`, there is no `A` annotation for the field. Try `User.class.getRecordComponents()[0].getAnnotations();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67074911/what-annotation-targets-are-applicable-to-java-records/ It's not identical, but once you understand which annotations are propagated and how, it should be fairly obvious why reflection is returning that result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Annotations on record components are propagated to potentially four places in the classfile:

- fields
- accessor methods
- constructor arguments
- record components themselves.

These are gated by whether the annotation is applicable to

- `FIELD`
- `METHOD`
- `PARAMETER`
- `RECORD_COMPONENT`

it will be propagated to all the places it is applicable.  If it is not applicable to any of these, it is rejected at compile time.